# adding an event listener to impress.js

Tags: javascript, impress.js

I am using `impress.js` library to make a presentation. I would like to attach a listener for a `div` where if the slide has classes `present active`. Then, I would like to have a counter to be displayed on the slide. I tried to use `elem.addEventListener('change',function(){counter()},false)`, but it didn't work.

I would like to know if there is a way to attach an event to `impress:next` function.

Sincerely,
Abdul

Answer (score 3):

You can add a listener which will be executed on current step :

```
document.addEventListener("impress:starttransition", function (event) {
    yourFunction(event.detail.next.id); });

document.addEventListener("impress:stepenter", function (event) {
    yourFunction(event.target.id); });
```